# Seaborn palettes - prevent recycling of colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

Seaborn allows defining color palettes that contain multiple colors, useful for charts with many lines.  However, when setting the palette to one with multiple colors, only the first six are used, after which colors recycle, making it hard to distinguish lines. This can be overridden by explicitly calling the palette, but that's not convenient.  Is there a way to force the Seaborn current palette not to recycle colors, when more than 6 are defined?

Example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

# Define a palette with 8 colors
cmap = sb.blend_palette(["firebrick", "palegreen"], 8) 
sb.palplot(cmap)
```

[image: palette with 6 colors]

```
# Set the current palette to this; only 6 colors are used
sb.set_palette(cmap)
sb.palplot(sb.color_palette() )
```

[image: palette with 6 colors]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({x:[x*10, x*10+5, x*10+10] for x in range(8)})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(4,6))
# Using the current palette, colors repeat 
df.plot(ax=ax1) 
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1)) 
# using the palette that defined the current palette, colors don't repeat
df.plot(ax=ax2, color=cmap) 
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))  ;
```

[image: charts with 6 or 8 colors used]

Comment: smells like a seaborn bug to me.

Comment: Actually, I don't think so: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html It looks like it is doing what it is supposed to, it is just annoying.

Comment: Hmm, I still think it's buggy.  The docs say for n_colors, "Number of colors in the palette. If larger than the number of colors in the palette, they will cycle."  That implies that if not larger than the colors in the palette they will not recycle, but they still do.  I'll edit the question to illustrate this.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `set_palette` just grabs what palette is being used, not the instance object, hence why by default you get back a 6 item color cycle.

Comment: You're right, I think I have it now -- it needs to explicitly use n_numbers on set_palette, and then also on color_palette to show it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution (thanks to @tcaswell for the pointer): Set the palette explicitly using all colors:

```
# Setting the palette using defaults only finds 6 colors
sb.set_palette(cmap)
sb.palplot(sb.color_palette() )
sb.palplot(sb.color_palette(n_colors=8) )

# but setting the number of colors explicitly allows it to use them all
sb.set_palette(cmap, n_colors=8)
# Even though unless you explicitly request all the colors it only shows 6
sb.palplot(sb.color_palette() )
sb.palplot(sb.color_palette(n_colors=8) )
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
# In a chart, the palette now has access to all 8 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(4,3)) 
df.plot(ax=ax1) 
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1)) ;
```

[image]