# Creating a dark, reversed color palette in Seaborn

Tags: python, python-2.7, seaborn

I am creating a figure that contains several plots using a sequential palette like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math

figure = plt.figure(1)
x = range(1, 200)
n_plots = 10

with sns.color_palette('Blues_d', n_colors=n_plots):
    for offset in range(n_plots):
        plt.plot(x, [offset + math.sin(float(i) / 10) for i in range(len(x))])

figure.show()
```

However, I would like to reverse the color palette. [The tutorial](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) states that I can add `'_r'` to a palette name to reverse it and `'_d'` to make it "dark". But I do not appear to be able to do these together: `'_r_d'`, `'_d_r'`, `'_rd'` and `'_dr'` all produce errors. How can I create a dark, reversed palette?

Comment: Palettes are just lists, so you can always use the `reversed()` function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to post the details and explanation of the solution I used, because mwaskom's suggestion required a tweak. Using

```
with reversed(sns.color_palette('Blues_d', n_colors=n_plots)):
```

throws `AttributeError: __exit__`, I believe because the with statement requires an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, which the `reversed` iterator doesn't satisfy. If I use `sns.set_palette(reversed(palette))` instead of a with statement, the number of colors in the plot is ignored (the default of 6 is used - I have no idea why) even though the color scheme is obeyed. To solve this, I use `list.reverse()` method:

```
figure = plt.figure(1)
x = range(1, 200)
n_plots = 10
palette = sns.color_palette("Blues_d", n_colors=n_plots)
palette.reverse()

with palette:
    for offset in range(n_plots):
        plt.plot(x, [offset + math.sin(float(i) / 10) for i in range(len(x))])

figure.show()
```

**Edit:** I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26301347/604687) that the reason the `n_colors` argument was ignored in the call to `set_palette` was because the `n_colors` argument must also be specified in that call. Another solution is therefore:

```
figure = plt.figure(1)
x = range(1, 200)
n_plots = 10

sns.set_palette(reversed(sns.color_palette("Blues_d", n_plots)), n_plots)

for offset in range(n_plots):
    plt.plot(x, [offset + math.sin(float(i) / 10) for i in range(len(x))])

figure.show()
```